# Saving blank nested models issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, model

My rails 4 app has 3 models:

1. Store (has_many :products)
2. Product (has_many :product_fields and belongs_to :store and accepts_nested_attributes_for product_fields
3. Product_fields (has a belongs_to :product)

Product only has **store_id** and **id** fields. Product_fields has **string_content** and **text_content**. Basically, right now my store model looks like:

```
class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :products
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :products, :allow_destroy => true, :reject_if => :product_empty

   private

   def product_empty(a)
     a[:product_fields_attributes][:text_content].blank?
   end

end
```

If I create a new store without filling in text_content, the models correctly reject it (and no product or product_fields are created). Unfortunately, the problem is that if I actually *do* fill in text_content, then it still doesn't create it.

My rails console looks like:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"nFUg4ynXYyg99rPPPoa3uO/iHP4LT1XlOz3Vm3Zm4Z0=", "store"=>{"name"=>"Test", "products_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"type_of"=>"Book", "product_fields_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"text_content"=>"test1"}}}}}, "commit"=>"Create Store"}
```

---

My question is: How do I get the **reject_if** method to work on nested models? So, to be clear, I don't want to validate the nested models, I just want to not save products if it's associated product_field text_content is blank?.

Comment: If you mean product_fields_attributes inside your attributes, then yes it is possible. Do not forget to define accepts_nested_attributes for Porduct model if you want to use product_fields_attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean product_fields_attributes inside your attributes, then yes it is possible.

```
def product_empty(a)
     a[:product_fields_attributes].each do |field_id, params|
       return true if params[:text_content].blank?
     end
     return false
end
```

Your code didn't work because you were trying to reference :product_fields_attributes as a hash of attributes but on practice it is a hash of  :id => :params pairs. Consequently where params hash contains the attributes you need.

Comment: thanks for the answer. But if I **don't** want to create a product if all product_fields are blank, how do you do that?

Comment: You can validate presence of associated records using has_many :product_fields, inverse_of: :product Refer to this article for more details: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#presence . It should do the trick

Comment: I tried this, but didn't seem to work any differently?

Comment: Did you add validates :product_fields, presence: true to your product model?

Comment: I tried the edit, but this comes up with an error message if I leave it blank (because of the validates method). I want to allow blank products (meaning no error messages), I just don't want to create them.

Comment: And about the strong parameters, if I take out the reject_if, it works fine, so it's not the strong parameters. I don't really understand why my code isn't working?

Comment: Your code is not working because :product_fields_attributes is a hash that contains several nested attributes in :id => :attributes, but you are referencing it as it only contains one nested attribute. I have changed my response. Sorry, took me a while to understand what you want

Comment: Ok wow, thanks for explaining that. Don't be sorry, I didn't explain it very well. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

May be recursive validate associated model?

```
class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :products, validate: true
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :products, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

**Update 1:**
if required reject not valid record:

```
class Store < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :products, validate: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :products, :allow_destroy => true, reject_if: :invalid?

  private   
  def invalid?(attr)
    Product.new(attr).invalid?
  end    
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :store
  has_many :product_fields, validate: true

  validates :product_fields, :presence => true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :product_fields, :allow_destroy => true
end

class ProductField < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product

  validates :string_content, :presence => true
  validates :text_content, :presence => true
end
```

or custom validation method in ProductField model, like:

```
validate :require_all_fields 
def require_all_fields
  errors.add(:base, "required") unless ....
end
```

Comment: but I don't really want to validate the models, I just don't want to save them blank.